wake effect on downstream turbine
I want to perform fatigue analysis on downstream turbine blades, but I want to do this analysis with the aerodynamic forces caused by wake effects.Do you have a recommended solver to obtain such data?
I know these ; openfast - turbsim or sowfa but I dont know any knowledge about openfoam.
I can use fluent but the simulation will take too long.

QBlade and nuMAD, if anybody needs this knowledge.

Are these two software the answer to your question? If yes, you can mark it as so
